# XCUIApplication is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer, swift3

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, swift3, xcode8

This app worked great, I published and updated this app multiple times. I just migrated over to swift 3 from swift2.2 and now I get the following error:

> **XCUIApplication is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer**

My iOS Deployment Target in Info is 9.0 (see image below) so I'm not sure what is causing this. Note, I can build and run the app in simulator mode and on a physical device (I tried running on iPhone 6 & 6+ and it works fine). I am concerned going forward without addressing this issue. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Here is a screen grab (below) from *UITests.swift in Xcode of the line associated with this error (XCUIApplication is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer).

[image]

Comment: That's the deployment target of the project. What is the deployment target of the target (the test) which can be different ?

Comment: I am not sure. I don't see iOS version under the UITests Info.plist

Comment: Click on "Show project and target list" (top left) and then on the target > General

Comment: OK I did that (changed the deployment target under target > General from was 8.0 to 9.0, build run and I am still getting the same error?

Comment: Clean the project (⇧⌘K)

Comment: Clean the project (⇧⌘K)solved the problem and removed the error! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If cleaning the project doesn't work, you might need to make sure you're setting the right target iOS version on both the project:
[image: Xcode deployment target iOS version (project)]

...and the target(s):
[image: Xcode deployment target iOS version (target)]

Comment: Does not work. My IOS version in related settings is 9.3

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I had a post install hook in my podfile setting deployment-target

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem in some Pod. In my case running `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` fixed the problem.